# Autohotkey Script to reliably bring an application to the forefront

Tags: autohotkey

I'm looking for an AutoHotKey script (or anything else for that matter) that will allow me to associate bringing an application to the forefront with a keyboard shortcut (preferably a Function Key).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very basic solution. Create new .ahk script and run. When you press F7 the window will be activated. Edit your hotkey where I labelled it (keep the double colon). Edit the window title that you want activated.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2       ;// matches partial window titles


F7::                       ;// hotkey
   WinActivate, Firefox    ;// activate window with this title
return
```

Comment: how would this work with Chrome where the window title depends on which tab is open?

Comment: @KalamalkaKid as i remember, chrome window titles are of the form "HTML TITLE TAG TEXT - Google Chrome" so using "- Google Chrome" for the WinTitle param should work